# Production Database went into restoring mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Yesterday one of my production database went into restoring mode,but fortunately i recovered it using below query

```
USE MASTER
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Allow updates',1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO

EXEC SP_RESETSTATUS 'DatabaseNAME'
DBCC DBRECOVER('DatabaseName')
EXEC SP_CONFIGURE 'Allow updates',0
GO

RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
GO
```

It brought my database online, but I want to know why it went in restoring mode, I read SQL error log but I didn't get much information about it. Is the query I used to bring the database online correct? It is used to recover the database from suspect mode.

Comment: `RESTORE DATABASE DatabaseName WITH RECOVERY;` is the proper way to complete recovery.  To identify the root cause, perhaps someone can help you decipher the messages from the error log if you post them.

Comment: @DanGuzman I am not restoring any database, it was already live on production which went into Restoring mode suddenly.

Comment: The `RESTORE` syntax I posted does not actually perform a restore; it only invokes recovery.  Note there is no `FROM` clause so a restore is not performed.

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks ... Just want to ask one more thing, can a backup job put database into Restoring mode, post backup.?

Comment: I have not run into a case where backup would cause a restoring state,  Can you add a snippet of the SQL Server error log to your question?  I would expect some indication as to why the database state changed.

Comment: It sounds like someone did a backup `WITH NORECOVERY` to me.

Comment: Are you sure it's restoring mode? A DB gets into that state if someone did a restore with no recovery. Backups do not put databases in restoring mode. If you're just looking at the Object Explorer in SSMS, if the database was in restoring mode when you opened the browser, it doesn't get visually updated to regular online status even when restoring is completed. You have to right-click on databases and click refresh. Look in the current and last 2 SQL Server error logs. You might find entries on restore actions or something else that might tell you what happened.

Answer (score 1):

`(Restoring...)` is typically seen under two circumstances.

1. You're restoring a database, and have specified the `WITH NORECOVERY` option to allow, typically, log backups to be restored.  The last restore operation would *not* use the `WITH NORECOVERY` option, thereby directing SQL Server to run the recovery process on the database, and allow client access to it.
2. You've taken a *backup* of the database logfile, and have specified the `WITH NORECOVERY` option to ensure you have [backed up the tail of the log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/tail-log-backups-sql-server).  This option might be used to ensure no one can access the database in anticipation of migrating the database to a different server.  You may inadvertently use this option when running a transaction log backup via the GUI:

   [image]
3. While a database is being restored, it will show up as `RESTORING`.

You can test the tail log recovery scenario mentioned above in option 2 using this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

First, we create a database, and set it to FULL recovery:

```
USE master;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases d WHERE d.name = 'RestoringModeTest')
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE RestoringModeTest SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE RestoringModeTest;
END
GO
CREATE DATABASE RestoringModeTest;
ALTER DATABASE RestoringModeTest SET RECOVERY FULL;
BACKUP DATABASE RestoringModeTest TO DISK = 'NUL:';
BACKUP LOG RestoringModeTest TO DISK = 'NUL:';
GO
```

This shows the state of the database:

```
SELECT d.name
    , d.state_desc
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name = 'RestoringModeTest';
```

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════════╗
║       name        ║ state_desc ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ RestoringModeTest ║ ONLINE     ║
╚═══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Here we backup the tail of the log.  (NOTE, this is NOT a real backup, since the target is the NUL: device.  DO NOT USE THIS IN PRODUCTION!)

```
BACKUP LOG RestoringModeTest TO DISK = 'NUL:' WITH NORECOVERY;
```

Now, when we look at the state of the database:

```
SELECT d.name
    , d.state_desc
FROM sys.databases d
WHERE d.name = 'RestoringModeTest';
```

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════════╗
║       name        ║ state_desc ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════════╣
║ RestoringModeTest ║ RESTORING  ║
╚═══════════════════╩════════════╝
```

This statement will cause SQL Server to run the recovery process on the database to return it to the `ONLINE` state:

```
RESTORE DATABASE RestoringModeTest WITH RECOVERY;
```